# Display a default value after Group By based on a column value

Tags: group-by, teradata

After my group by, combine two values to one if specific value comes.

My select query with group by has State, city, and a direction column in group by. The direction column can have 3 values, either 'left', or 'right' or 'both'. Ideally only one direction comes for a city ( which means one row). So in cases where there is only left or right comes in, I have to show it, as is. Whereas in cases where, for a specific state and city if two records show up - say one as right and other as left; then only one record with direction as 'Both' should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, remove `direction` from grouping and move it to CASE:

```
select State, city
   ,case when min(direction) = max(direction) -- only one direction
         then max(direction)                  -- -> return it
         else 'both'
    end
from tab
group by State, city
```